# Filter object of objects for specific key/value in JavaScript in AngularJs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an object of objects (JSON), and I am trying to get the value of a certain object.

I have done some searching and I am struggling to get the correct answer, or how to implement it correctly.

I have seen the following suggestion of filtering objects, and was hoping to get some guidance on how to implement this or a better or other working solution:

```
var myKeys = Object.keys(myObject)
var matchingKey = myKeys.indexOf("expected") !== -1 // to check whether there is a match
var matchingKeys = myKeys.filter(function("expected"){ return key.indexOf("expected") !== -1 });
var matchingValues = matchingKeys .map(function(key){ return myObject[key] });
```

**My data looks like this:**

```
{
  "production_deploys": {
    "2017-04-21": {
      "success": 2
    }, 
    "2017-05-02": {
      "failures": 3, 
      "success": 2
    }
  }, 
  "pull_requests": {
    "2017-04-04": 1
  }, 
  "test_deploys": {
    "2017-04-04": {
      "success": 1
    }, 
    "2017-04-20": {
      "success": 1
    }, 
    "2017-04-21": {
      "success": 1
    }
  }, 
  "uptime": {
    "2017-04-24": {
      "failures": 9, 
      "successes": 150
    }, 
    "2017-04-25": {
      "failures": 3, 
      "successes": 50
    }, 
    "expected": 95.0
  }
}
```

And **I am trying to retrieve the value of "expected"**. Which in this case is **95.0**. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

**Note:** It is an AngularJs app, so angular-filter could be an option?

Comment: `myObject.uptime.expected`?

Comment: @James I think that is part of why I struggle so much today. I did not truly notice it was part of .uptime. I was trying myObject.expected. Can you perhaps give me a pointer on the filtering?

Comment: Well, if the expected uptime is always in that same spot do you need to filter?  If you expect to have to search through your list data I would recommend using arrays for your "list" properties (like test_deploys and pull_requests) and use the builtin array filter/find/map functions.

Comment: @James I do believe it will be in the same spot, so `myObject.uptime.expected` should word. Otherwise I will do some more research. Thanks for the help!